# How do I get my v-show to display a component in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to render a component only when a condition is met. I have no problem with `v-if`, i.e. the component renders only when the condition is met. But I prefer to use `v-show` (as I anticipate frequent toggling by the user).

The html has something like this

```html
    <Moe v-show="isMoe" />
    <Larry />
    <Curly />
```

The script has something like this

```js
    import Moe from "@/components/Moe.vue";
    import Larry from "@/components/Larry.vue";
    import Curly from "@/components/Curly.vue";

    export default {
      data: function() {
        return {
          stooge: "Curly"
        }
      },
      components, {
        Moe,
        Larry,
        Curly
      },
      computed: {
        isMoe() {
          return this.stooge == "Moe"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Addendum**
If `this.stooge = "Curly"`, the Moe component still renders

Comment: Could you explain what problem you’re having also?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If this.stooge == "Curly", the Moe component still renders. If I use v-if, that's when I get the desired effect

Comment: This code has a breaking typo:  `components, {`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `v-show`. The code works as expected.

Comment: @Gino Mempin What version of Vue are you using? Mine is 2.6.11

Comment: Same, vue@2.6.11. Though, I don't know what the `<template>` looks like to match the posted `<script>`, but I wrapped Moe, Curly, and Larry in a `<div>`.

Comment: @Gino Mempin Much as I would like to dig deeper into my code and see why v-show is not working on the component, I'll just leave my fix as is. Don't really have the luxury of time to make my code elegant

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by placing the component inside a div tag and moving the v-show on the parent div. Here's a adjusted code:

```
<div v-show="isMoe">
  <Moe />
</div>
<Larry />
<Curly />



import Moe from "@/components/Moe.vue";
import Larry from "@/components/Larry.vue";
import Curly from "@/components/Curly.vue";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      stooge: "Curly"
    }
  },
  components: {
    Moe,
    Larry,
    Curly
  },
  computed: {
    isMoe() {
      return this.stooge === "Moe"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `v-show` on `<Moe v-show="isMoe" />` now since its on parent div.

Comment: @ambianBeing I've corrected the code. Much obliged, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a terminology issue, but `v-show` will always render a component. It will simply add a `style="display: none;"` style and toggle that to `block`.

Your code looks correct so it should behave as expected. Is it not adding the `style="display: none;"` when v-show is `false`?

As an additional note. It is better practice to use `===` instead of `==`:

```js
return this.stooge === "Moe"
```

Comment: I've enclosed each component in its div tag and placed the v-show on the div. It worked. P.S. I've used === instead of == as suggested